# Why does Magisk not run my script on boot?

Tags: samsung, rooting, magisk, scripts

I have Android 10, Samsung a7. I have root by custom firmware + Magisk.

I tried to put script in:

```
/data/adb/service.d/myscript
/data/adb/post-fs-data.d/myscript
/system/etc/init.d/myscript
```

But it doesn't run.

Where I can put my script to execute after boot system?

Script to execute:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

sleep 100

is_charging()
{
    [ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/status) = Charging ] || [ $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/status) = Full ] || return 1
}

# keep waiting
while is_charging; do sleep 1; done

# charger is disconnected, countdown
sleep 300

# again start waiting if charger is connected
is_charging && exec $(realpath $0)

# else, shutdown
/system/bin/reboot -p charger_disconnected ||
/system/bin/setprop sys.powerctl shutdown,charger_disconnected
```

Comment: What was exactly in the script? Are you sure it didn't have errors? Did you make the file executable? Did you check Magisk log or `logcat`? Did you try to redirect script's `stdout`/`stderr` to `logcat` or a file?

Comment: Thank you for interested my problem. I edited post, added script. 
I'm programmer javascript, node, python, but android I'm noob.

I have second phone (older, android 5.0) and the same script did works, I put it to `init.d` file.

So if this script did works correctly to another device I think so, i didn't have errors in the script.

As you can see, my script turn off/turn on phone, when is charging battery or isn't.
`Did you make the file executable?`
How I can do it? I just created file and I changed chmod 0755.
Now I checked logs in magisk, I have log: service.d exec [myfilescrip]

Comment: `Did you try to redirect script's stdout/stderr to logcat or a file?` No, I haven't tried, I don't know what it is, how can I do it and why.

Comment: the script was executed but magisk kills blocking scripts after 10 seconds

Comment: I tried in `adb shell` on the root  execute `/system/bin/reboot -p charger_disconnected ||
/system/bin/setprop sys.powerctl shutdown,charger_disconnected` and my system has shut down.

I do understand correctly - my script executed, but my "sleep(100)" (over 10 second) kill everythink what is later execute? I have to have sleep, how I can check it, maybe magisk setup I can change?